# BooleanField value return always false

Tags: django, django-forms

I need to get the value of Django form checkbox in the `view.py`.
I always get the value `False`, even when I expect it to be `True`.

My code is:

**`forms.py`**

```
class PointForm(forms.ModelForm):
    checkboxSGEquipTypeTagAll = forms.BooleanField(
        label='override',
        widget=forms.CheckboxInput(attrs={
            'id': 'checkboxSGEquipTypeTagAll'
        }),
        required=False,
    )
```

**view**

```
logging.debug(form.cleaned_data['checkboxSGEquipTypeTagAll'])
```

or:

```
 logging.debug(form['checkboxSGEquipTypeTagAll'].value())
```

Comment: Show your template and your view.

Comment: actually its now solved. The problem was I forget to add this checkbox inside the <form> ...